# Bash Verify date format

Tags: bash

I try to check, if input is correct. The input is correct if looks like YYYY-MM-DD. I try to write a function, but I get failed result.

```
function reg_exp 
{
    if [[ $1 =~ [0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} ]]
    then echo "true"
    else echo "false"
    fi
}

>reg_exp 2015-10-20
true

# but for the parameter "2015-10-200" the results is failed....
> reg_exp 2015-10-200
true
```

Where is the mistake?

Comment: Shouldn't you add a '*' or a '%' at the end?

Comment: It's a shame `bash` didn't completely copy `ksh`'s extended patterns. You could write `[[ $1 = {4}([0-9])-{2}([0-9])-{2}([0-9]) ]]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are checking only that that pattern exists in your input. To check that the pattern is all of the input, try:

```
function reg_exp 
{
    if [[ $1 =~ ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$ ]]
    then echo "true"
    else echo "false"
    fi
}
```

The `^` means beginning of string and the `$` means end of string.

Answer (score 1):

As your format matches the one of `date`, you can use it to validate your date instead of using a regex. It will check for leap years and specific number of days per month :

```
check_date() {
    if date -d "$1" &>/dev/null
        then echo true
    else
         echo false
    fi
}
```

Comment: We can combine the 2 approaches: `check_date() { [[ $1 =~ ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$ ]] && date -d "$1" &>/dev/null; }`